# Java List.SubList() Performance comparison

Tags: java, list, sublist

I need to implement a sliding window which slides over a sequence. (1:[0,1,2,3]2:[1,2,3,4],...)
Which aprove might be faster?
1.

```
for each step i; {List=wholeList.sublist(i,i+windowlen)}
```

or 2.

```
  List window=wholeList.sublist(0,window);
  for each i{
  window.remove(0);
  window.add(i+windowlen);
```

}

?

I measured the time with system.currtime bla .. +-std the SubLists seems to work faster.. but why? i think the second aproach is O(n)

I need to operate huge databases.. therefor i need to look at this..

mfg
Jan

Comment: Please edit your post to format the two code alternatives. It isn't clear whether the remove step is part of both or not.

Comment: Jan - we can't help you if your Question / code is so poorly presented that we can't figure out what you are talking about.  Fix it please.

Comment: In addition to the above, I'd like to point out that it is meaningless to talk about performance of Java data structures / algorithms cast in terms of the interface abstractions.  You need to mention the actual classes used.  They make a crucial difference.

Comment: I suggest that you write some real Java code, compile it test it, measure it.  If you questions based on the results of that, ask a new question, including the actual code that you have written/tested/measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the remove step is only part of step 2, they aren't equivalent, so comparing them is pointless. The second one modifies both the subsist and the underlying list. I doubt whether (2) will even work. I don't see any reason to go beyond (1).

Comment: why should the underlying list change if i write values from it in another list.. or should i build the initial list first by adding windowlen-many objects to the "window-list"... maybe therefore it takes so long. anyway i have to try to work with arrays.. seems that i dont really understand sublists. The code was very shorthand sry for that.

Comment: A `subList` is just a window onto the original list, and modifying it will modify the original list.

Comment: Because that's what it says in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)): 'The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa'.